# Android BottomSheetDialogFragment that does not take whole width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How do I make BottomSheetDialogFragment that does not cover entire width of the screen (something like "Share via" sheet in Chrome on tablets)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible right now:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204670

Answer (score 6):

As a developer suggested in the issue linked by @UfoXp, the problem is `BottomSheetDialog.onCreate()` setting the window to `MATCH_PARENT` both ways:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    if ((isTablet(getContext()) || isLandscape(getContext()))) {
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogINterface) {
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            }
        });
    }
    return dialog;
}

private boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}

private boolean isLandscape(Context context) {
    return context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `getWindow().setLayout()` after showing the Dialog

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: In my case its only working if I add it to "setOnShowListener" or even better to put it to bottomSheetDialog.create().apply {} then there would be no visible transitions